# icon of a removed app still in Launchpad

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I had install gimp and now i remove it with AppClener but the icon of gimp still in Launchpad with "?". Why done this? How can i remove? (pic of my Launchpad: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/11/screenshot20120201at529.png/ )

Comment: i try it.. but nothing..icon still in Launchpad..

Answer (score 0):

1. `cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/`
2. make a backup of all the *.db file under that directory;
3. `sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db 'DELETE FROM apps;' 
   && killall Dock`

The data in the Launchpad's database will be refreshed.

You can refer the hint at http://www.cultofmac.com/106030/how-to-nuke-lions-launchpad-and-start-over/